# async_work_group_copy is copying data slower than manual copying in opencl kernel

Tags: opencl

In my opencl kernel, I am trying to copy part of the data which is accessed more than other parts to the local memory. To do that, at the beginning I was just assigining the values manually. The copying was as follows:

```
    __global LinearBVHInteriorNode* subtree_globalptr           =  &(((__global BVHTree*)accelstruct)->interior_nodes[subtree_interior_idx]);
    __global LinearBVHInteriorNodeInfo* subtree_info_globalptr  =  &(((__global BVHTree*)accelstruct)->interior_nodes_info[subtree_interior_idx]);

    int last_subtree_interior_idx  = subtree_info_globalptr->last_interior;

    int n_subtree_interior_nodes = last_subtree_interior_idx - subtree_interior_idx + 1;

    int interior_nodes_beg_idx = thread_local_idx * ((n_subtree_interior_nodes / local_dim) + 1);
    int interior_nodes_end_idx = min((thread_local_idx + 1) * ((n_subtree_interior_nodes / local_dim) + 1), last_subtree_interior_idx);

    if(thread_local_idx == 0){
      subtree.interior_base_idx = subtree_info_globalptr[1].parent;
      subtree.leaf_base_idx     = subtree_info_globalptr[0].leaf_lowidx;
      subtree.tree              = accelstruct;
    }

    // Copy the data for interior nodes from the global memory to local memory
    for(int i = interior_nodes_beg_idx; i <= interior_nodes_end_idx; i++){

      subtree.interior_nodes[ i ].left_bound.min  = subtree_globalptr[ i ].left_bound.min;
      subtree.interior_nodes[ i ].left_bound.max  = subtree_globalptr[ i ].left_bound.max;
      subtree.interior_nodes[ i ].right_bound.min = subtree_globalptr[ i ].right_bound.min;
      subtree.interior_nodes[ i ].right_bound.max = subtree_globalptr[ i ].right_bound.max;
      subtree.interior_nodes[ i ].children[0]     = subtree_globalptr[ i ].children[0];
      subtree.interior_nodes[ i ].children[1]     = subtree_globalptr[ i ].children[1];
      subtree.interior_nodes[ i ].splitAxis       = subtree_globalptr[ i ].splitAxis;
    }

    int leafnodes_lowidx                                = subtree_info_globalptr->leaf_lowidx;
    int leafnodes_highidx                               = subtree_info_globalptr->leaf_highidx;
    int n_subtree_leaf_nodes                            = leafnodes_highidx - leafnodes_lowidx;
    __global LinearBVHLeafNode* subtree_leaf_globalptr =  &(((__global BVHTree*)accelstruct)->leaf_nodes[leafnodes_lowidx]);

    int leaf_nodes_beg_idx = thread_local_idx * ((n_subtree_leaf_nodes / local_dim) + 1);
    int leaf_nodes_end_idx = min((thread_local_idx + 1) * ((n_subtree_leaf_nodes / local_dim) + 1), leafnodes_highidx);

    // Copy the data for leaf nodes from the global memory to local memory
    for(int i = leaf_nodes_beg_idx; i < leaf_nodes_end_idx; i++){

      subtree.leaf_nodes[ i ].lowIdx  = subtree_leaf_globalptr[ i ].lowIdx;
      subtree.leaf_nodes[ i ].highIdx = subtree_leaf_globalptr[ i ].highIdx;
    }

  // Wait all the threads to finish the copying task.
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
```

it tooks 0.1s for my dataset to copy the data from global memory to local memory which is too much. As I understood the `async_work_group_copy` should perform it faster than manual copying, so I changed to `async_work_group_copy`:

```
    __global LinearBVHInteriorNode* subtree_globalptr           =  &(((__global BVHTree*)accelstruct)->interior_nodes[subtree_interior_idx]);
    __global LinearBVHInteriorNodeInfo* subtree_info_globalptr  =  &(((__global BVHTree*)accelstruct)->interior_nodes_info[subtree_interior_idx]);

    int last_subtree_interior_idx  = subtree_info_globalptr->last_interior;

    int n_subtree_interior_nodes = last_subtree_interior_idx - subtree_interior_idx + 1;

    int interior_nodes_beg_idx = thread_local_idx * ((n_subtree_interior_nodes / local_dim) + 1);
    int interior_nodes_end_idx = min((thread_local_idx + 1) * ((n_subtree_interior_nodes / local_dim) + 1), last_subtree_interior_idx);

    if(thread_local_idx == 0){
      subtree.interior_base_idx = subtree_info_globalptr[1].parent;
      subtree.leaf_base_idx     = subtree_info_globalptr[0].leaf_lowidx;
      subtree.tree              = accelstruct;
    }

    event_t copy_events[2];

    // Copy the data for interior nodes from the global memory to local memory
    copy_events[0] = async_work_group_copy((__local long2*)(&subtree.interior_nodes[ interior_nodes_beg_idx ]), (__global long2 *)(&subtree_globalptr[ interior_nodes_beg_idx ]), (interior_nodes_end_idx - interior_nodes_beg_idx + 1) * 5, 0);

    int leafnodes_lowidx                                = subtree_info_globalptr->leaf_lowidx;
    int leafnodes_highidx                               = subtree_info_globalptr->leaf_highidx;
    int n_subtree_leaf_nodes                            = leafnodes_highidx - leafnodes_lowidx;
    __global LinearBVHLeafNode* subtree_leaf_globalptr =  &(((__global BVHTree*)accelstruct)->leaf_nodes[leafnodes_lowidx]);

    int leaf_nodes_beg_idx = thread_local_idx * ((n_subtree_leaf_nodes / local_dim) + 1);
    int leaf_nodes_end_idx = min((thread_local_idx + 1) * ((n_subtree_leaf_nodes / local_dim) + 1), leafnodes_highidx);

    // Copy the data for leaf nodes from the global memory to local memory
    copy_events[1] = async_work_group_copy((__local long*)&subtree.interior_nodes[ leaf_nodes_beg_idx ], (__global long*)&subtree_globalptr[ leaf_nodes_beg_idx ], (leaf_nodes_end_idx - leaf_nodes_beg_idx), 0);


  // Wait all the threads to finish the copying task.
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
```

But it performs the copying in `1.0s` which is very strange. The struct which I have used are defined as follows:

```
typedef struct {
  AABB      left_bound, right_bound;
  int       children[2];
  ushort    splitAxis;
  int       pad;

} LinearBVHInteriorNode;

typedef struct {
  int       parent;
  int       leaf_lowidx, leaf_highidx;
  int       last_interior;

} LinearBVHInteriorNodeInfo;

typedef struct {
  int  lowIdx, highIdx;
} LinearBVHLeafNode;

typedef struct {
  int  parent;
} LinearBVHLeafNodeInfo;

typedef struct {
  __global  LinearBVHInteriorNode*      interior_nodes;         //!< a pointer to interior nodes
  __global  LinearBVHInteriorNodeInfo*  interior_nodes_info;    //!< a pointer to information of interior nodes
  __global  LinearBVHLeafNode*          leaf_nodes;             //!< a pointer to leaf nodes 
  __global  LinearBVHLeafNodeInfo*      leaf_nodes_info;        //!< a pointer to information of leaf nodes
  uint      n_interior_nodes;                                   //!< Number of interior nodes
  uint      n_leaf_nodes;                                       //!< Number of leaf nodes
} BVHTree;


typedef struct {
  __local LinearBVHInteriorNode* interior_nodes;
  __local LinearBVHLeafNode*     leaf_nodes;

  int     interior_base_idx, leaf_base_idx;

  __global BVHTree*              tree;
} local_BVHTree;
```

I was looking for a function like `memcpy` in opencl kernel. because both of the arrays has the same structure and can be copied with such instruction. I think `async_work_group_copy` is doing something similar. Anyone ever had the same problem?

Comment: What are you using for that data in the local memory? Do you really need to perform the full copy? I am guessing that maybe the compiler is realizing that you don't really use all the copied data and is avoiding the copy. While in the other approach it is not optimizing it out, due to the constrain of the "block copy" the async does.

Comment: @DarkZeros I am trying to copy a part of a Bounding Volume Hierarchy and I am using most part of it. Also, it is not possible for compiler to guess about which part of the tree is going to be used or not, so it can realize that it should not be copied.

Comment: @DarkZeros Also, do you think copying 32 KBytes can take 100 ms for GPU? Something should be wrong in my code. I will look for it.

Comment: In my case `async_work_group_copy` makes the kernel run few times slower than manual copying when run on CPU. I did not observe that issue on nvidia gpu.

Comment: @doqtor have you tried with AMD gpus? I am using amd r9 280x. On the CPU, it makes sense because the CPU does not have local memory at all but for gpu it should get faster.

Comment: @mmostajab The speed difference between `async_work_group_copy` and manual copying should have nothing to do with how local memory is represented on CPU. It's rather to do what `async_work_group_copy` is internally doing so that it makes it slower or it requires special treatment when run on CPU. Anyway I tried on amd r9 295 and no issues observed.